# How to update positions for two inline inputs independently?

Tags: html, css, web

I've been trying to create some login text/button tab. When I try changing the position, it changes both the username and password tags. How to approach it so that it changes only one as I don't want them two to be at the same position. I've tried to apply separate CSS classes to tags and move them, but it doesn't show them on-screen then.
What I have currently done:

```css
.loginbox input[type="text"], input[type="password"] {
  right: 100%;
  border:none;
  border-bottom:ipx solid#fff;
  background: transparent;
  outline: none;
  color: #000;
  font-size: 16px;
  position: relative;
  right: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="loginbox">
  <input type = "text" class = "userclass" name = "" placeholder = "Insert Username">
  <input type = "text" class = "passclass" name = "" placeholder = "Insert Password">
</div>
```

What am I missing?

Comment: could you explain more specifically? i can't catch what you want.

Comment: Oh sorry, first time using the website so I wasn't really sure. I'm attempting to get 2 text tag's I've created to be on the top-right of the screen. It works when I do this using the css, but it puts them both at the same exact spot. I'm trying to put them both in different positions, but being in the same general area so the user can actually read what they say.

Comment: Use separate positions for both of them. Make separate classes, put different `margin-right` values. It will help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use these HTML & CSS. Tell me if you are getting proper result or not.

Without the use of `.loginbox input[]` in CSS:

```css
.loginbox {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
}

.userclass {
  position: relative;
  margin-right: 25px;
}

.passclass {
  position: relative;
  margin-right: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="loginbox">
  <input type="text" class="userclass" name="" placeholder="Insert Username">
  <input type="password" class="passclass" name="" placeholder="Insert Password">
</div>
```

With `.loginbox input[]` in CSS:

```css
.loginbox {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
}

.loginbox input[type="text"], input[type="password"] {
  border:none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
  background: transparent;
  outline: none;
  color: #000;
  font-size: 16px;
  position: relative;
  right: 50px;
}

.userclass {
  margin-right: 25px;
}

.passclass {
  margin-right: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="loginbox">
  <input type="text" class="userclass" name="" placeholder="Insert Username">
  <input type="password" class="passclass" name="" placeholder="Insert Password">
</div>
```

Comment: should I get rid of the '.loginbox input[]' css?

Comment: I think you can go away without that if not necessary. But if you think it's necessary to you, then you can follow my 2nd code.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply target the `userclass` and `passclass` classes themselves, with `.userclass` and `.passclass` respectively.

If you have other elements that make use of these classes, you can explicitly ensure that they are direct children of the `loginbox` class with the child combinator `>`, as can be seen in the following.

Note that `right` does not apply to `position: relative`, and if you wish to use it, you'll need to set their `position` to `absolute` instead:

```css
.loginbox > .userclass {
  position: absolute;
  right: 175px;
}

.loginbox > .passclass {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="loginbox">
  <input type="text" class="userclass" name="" placeholder="Insert Username">
  <input type="text" class="passclass" name="" placeholder="Insert Password">
</div>
```

If instead you wish to use relative positioning (which I recommend), you can use `margin-right` instead, with an absolutely-positioned parent:

```css
.loginbox {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
}

.loginbox > .userclass {
  position: relative;
  margin-right: 25px;
}

.loginbox > .passclass {
  position: relative;
  margin-right: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="loginbox">
  <input type="text" class="userclass" name="" placeholder="Insert Username">
  <input type="text" class="passclass" name="" placeholder="Insert Password">
</div>
```

Comment: Hello, the inputs go out of the screen again once I use this, no matter the px value.

Comment: @vg101 can you share a screenshot?

Comment: Ok, here is the screenshot after adding the .loginbox { part https://imgur.com/a/MOwsuHi

Comment: @vg101 are you using the code given in the answer? Or are you using your codes? Only the CSS parts matter to me.

Comment: I used the CSS given, the CSS I had used before also showed the same result.